# .org Source for Org Manual?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to learn Org Mode well by reading the whole org manual. However there seem to be only HTML version and PDF version which are not very convenient for me to take notes while reading. Is there an `.org` version of the manual or some way to produce an easily notable version?

Comment: Talking about pdf and taking notes in org-mode, check out the [`interleave`](https://github.com/rudolfochrist/interleave) package, also available on Melpa.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Cool, seems nice. Though there's an issue that `DocView` is still quite laggy especially for large pdf files...

Comment: I have been using `pdf-tools` without any problem for using an 1300+ page pdf files for reference. It's so convenient that I've even bound that pdf file to a [key binding](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/tree/c774ee838e174c2e5f310a9f138dcf68537ebd76/setup-files/setup-misc.el#L198-L200).

Answer (score 2):

There is an out-of-date (~2 years old) version of the manual hosted on github [Org Manual](https://github.com/tsdye/orgmanual).

The Org format is capable of supporting the majority of the Info format and can certainly cross-link well enough to handle the requirements (The issue it has with info is formatting the correct types of `@?ref` since it does not distinguish between types of links).  It does not however support appendices (natively, they can be added in using org macros).

Initially there was no exporter for `texinfo`, I built `ox-texinfo` following the creation of the new `ox-` export framework.

Answer (score 2):

Just head over to

> https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/doc/org-manual.org

and copy the raw text into an org file.

Comment: if you have wget: `(shell-command "wget https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/raw/master/doc/org-manual.org -O /path/to/org-manual.org")`

Comment: ... or `wget https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/raw/master/doc/org-manual.org`. If you have a full Org mode distribution (e.g. from git) , then the manual for your version should be in `doc/org-manual.org`. The manual has been available as an Org mode file since 9.1.10 I think.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind it seems that the org documentation was written in `Texinfo` and the source was available at org distribution itself http://orgmode.org/org-8.2.10.tar.gz or http://orgmode.org/org-8.2.10.zip . Maybe tools like `pandoc` will do the conversion.

Edit: Actually the `info` format of the file was really fine. I could directly browse it nicely in `Emacs` and take notes side-by-side. Use `M-x org-info` to open the manual directly or find the info file inside of the distribution.

Comment: This is because Org as a format isn't good enough for the project to be used as basis, both because it doesn't support Info manuals and cross-linking well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Org mode release 9.2, the Org mode manual has been converted to an Org mode file ([`doc/org-manual.org`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/doc/org-manual.org)) and the various other versions of it (texinfo, PDF, HTML) have been produced from it using the Org mode exporter. See the [Makefile](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/doc/Makefile) in the `doc/` directory for the rules that are used to make the derived files.

To get a local copy of `org-manual.org`:

1. Pick a PATH.
2. Retrieve manual:

```el
(url-copy-file "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/plain/doc/org-manual.org" "PATH/org-manual.org")
```

N.B. If you want to process[1] the above file in Emacs as an Org mode file, you will also need to copy the `doc-setup.org` file:

```el
(url-copy-file "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/plain/doc/doc-setup.org" "PATH/doc-setup.org")
```

3. Create an `org-link` to the manual:

```
[[PATH/org-manual.org][The Org Manual]]
```

If you [have cloned the Org mode git repository](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html), the Org mode version of the manual (as well as that of `org-guide) is available locally already:

```shell
cd /some/path
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs/org-mode.git
cd /some/path/org-mode/doc
ls -l org-manual.org org-guide.org
```

so you can link to that. That is the latest version of the manual, but once you clone the repo, you can check out whatever version you are currently running so that the manual and your version will be in sync. You will have to update your repo periodically to get newer changes of course.

EDIT:

If you just need to open the latest version of org-manual in org format from time to time, you can add a function to your init:

```el
(defun my/org-manual()
  (interactive)
  (url-copy-file "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/plain/doc/org-manual.org" "~/tmp/tmp.org" t)
  (find-file "~/tmp/tmp.org"))
```

Then `M-x my/org-manual` will then open the manual in org.

---

[1] But note that "processing" the file is a bit more than exporting it: it needs some preparation before you can export it. See the link to the `doc/Makefile` above for what needs to be done.

Comment: @NickD, I can open `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bzg/org-mode/main/doc/org-manual.org` in Emacs without anything else (no need of `doc-setup.org`)

Comment: You can open it but you cannot process it without the `doc-setup.org` file - so you either have a local `doc-setup.org` in the same directory or you are ignoring the warning (check `*Messages*` after you open the file). Search the file for a `#+setupfile` directive. In any case, the savannah URL is the official git repo for Org mode, so it is likely to stay alive even if @bzg stops syncing his Github repo with it.

Comment: I fixed the wording: `open` --> `process`

Comment: And in fact, @bzg's copy is slightly out of date: it has a 2022 copyright, whereas the "official" one has a 2023 copyright and the diff shows a number of changes. So he has not synced in a little while.

Comment: By process you mean export? Because even with `doc-setup.org` export fails.

Comment: The process is more complicated: see the doc/Makefile I linked to above to see what needs to be done. But yes, fundamentally it's an export: it just needs to be dressed up appropriately before it succeeds.

Comment: BTW, thanks for answering the question: I think it's better with my edits, but I wouldn't even have known about it if you hadn't started the ball rolling.

Comment: Indeed it is much better with your edits, thanks for the additions.